# Identifying Outlook mail with specific subject from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code for extracting tables from Outlook email.

It only looks at the latest email. I need to a match string in the subject of the email to identify which email to extract from.

What do I need to add to the code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub impOutlookTable()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents

' point to the desired email
Const strMail As String = "first.last@outlook.com"

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
If (oApp Is Nothing) Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")

On Error GoTo 0

Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")
Set oMail = oMapi.Items(oMapi.Items.Count)

' get html table from email object
Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
With oHTML
    .Body.innerHTML = oMail.HTMLBody
    Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
End With

'import in Excel
Dim x As Long, y As Long
For x = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows.Length - 1
    For y = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
        Range("A1").Offset(x, y).Value = oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
    Next y
Next x

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMapi = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oHTML = Nothing
Set oElColl = Nothing

wkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\Outlook\tables.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to retrieve one email with the specified subject:

```
If oMapi.Items.Item(i).Subject = "Your subject here" Then 

'Some code here

End if
```

If you want to retrieve all emails with the specified subject:

```
For i = 1 To oMapi.Items.Count 
  If oMapi.Items.Item(i).Subject = "Your subject here" Then 
    'Some code here 
  End If 
Next i
```

I haven't tested it but it would be somewhere along those lines, you can see [Microsoft Online documentation for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-subject-property-outlook)

Comment: I'm only looking for one email that matches the subject. I put the first option after the following code: Set oMail = oMapi.Items(oMapi.Items.Count). However, it looks like its only looking at the last email to match the subject. I need it to look in the entire inbox, and then extract the table from the email that matches (whether its the last one or not)

Comment: The first option only checks if the condition is met and if that is the case, executes the code between if and end if. You may want to test the second option which iterates all emails

Comment: I just tried and the "For i = 0 ...." is causing an error of "Object doesn't support property or method". Any ideas?

Comment: I tested it this morning and it worked for me, is your oMapi object being set properly during the execution of code? If it is not set it will return an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176171/discussion-between-yousuf-and-frankviii).